# Mail doesn't get sent out using Apache Commons Mail

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, apache-commons, apache-commons-email

I'm using version 1.3.3 Apache Commons Mail for sending out emails. I've tried

- changing the Apache mail version
- using telnet smtp.gmail.com 587 to test for connectivity (it works, so its not about the firewall)
- trying out with different ports
- setting SSL/ TSL and tried other bunch of methods
- configured my gmail to enable IMAP, POP

but still the mail is not sending out.

this is the debug message i had, googled for solution, but none that solve the problem i have

```
DEBUG: JavaMail version 1.4ea
DEBUG: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_67\jre\lib\javamail.providers (The system cannot find the file specified)
DEBUG: URL jar:file:/C:/Users/doreenlohjw/.m2/repository/org/jvnet/mock-  javamail/mock-javamail/1.9/mock-javamail-1.9.jar!/META-INF/javamail.providers
DEBUG: Bad provider entry: 
DEBUG: successfully loaded resource:    jar:file:/C:/Users/doreenlohjw/.m2/repository/org/jvnet/mock-javamail/mock-   javamail/1.9/mock-javamail-1.9.jar!/META-INF/javamail.providers
DEBUG: successfully loaded resource: /META-INF/javamail.default.providers
DEBUG: Tables of loaded providers
DEBUG: Providers Listed By Class Name: {com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtps,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport,Sun Microsystems, Inc], com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Sun Microsystems, Inc], com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imaps,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore,Sun Microsystems, Inc], org.jvnet.mock_javamail.MockStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imap,org.jvnet.mock_javamail.MockStore,java.net mock-javamail project], com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3s,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore,Sun Microsystems, Inc], org.jvnet.mock_javamail.MockTransport=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,org.jvnet.mock_javamail.MockTransport,java.net mock-javamail project], com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imap,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore,Sun Microsystems, Inc], com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store,Sun Microsystems, Inc]}
DEBUG: Providers Listed By Protocol: {imaps=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imaps,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore,Sun Microsystems, Inc], imap=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imap,org.jvnet.mock_javamail.MockStore,java.net mock-javamail project], smtps=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtps,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport,Sun Microsystems, Inc], pop3=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3,org.jvnet.mock_javamail.MockStore,java.net mock-javamail project], pop3s=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3s,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore,Sun Microsystems, Inc], smtp=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,org.jvnet.mock_javamail.MockTransport,java.net mock-javamail project]}
DEBUG: successfully loaded resource: /META-INF/javamail.default.address.map
DEBUG: !anyLoaded
DEBUG: not loading resource: /META-INF/javamail.address.map
DEBUG: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_67\jre\lib\javamail.address.map (The system cannot find the file specified)
DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,org.jvnet.mock_javamail.MockTransport,java.net mock-javamail project]
```

and my code as of below,

```
MultiPartEmail email = new MultiPartEmail();
email.setSmtpPort(587);
email.setHostName("smtp.gmail.com");
email.setAuthentication("xxx@gmail.com", "xxx");
email.setDebug(true);
email.setStartTLSEnabled(true);
email.setFrom(from);
email.setSubject(subject);
email.setMsg(msg);
email.addTo(to);
email.attach(attachment);
email.send();
```

Comment: I am not sure, but it seems you have a mailing mock service in your classpath. Guessing from the name I'd guess that this implementation won't send out a real mail ...

Comment: mail.transport.protocol   can you check this property.

Comment: @DaDaDom thats worked! i removed the mock javamail dependency, and everything worked like a treat. Thanks! Reply as an answer, so i can accept it as an answer.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you have a mailing mock service in your classpath. Guessing from the name I'd guess that this implementation won't send out a real mail.

So please try to remove that library from the classpath and try again.

I you use maven, you can set the `scope` of that mock dependency to `test`.